# Distinct terms not being identified correctly in MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python, unicode-string

I have created a database which stores a simple inverted index created from Bengali text documents.

Table Name: simple_index , Primary key {Term, Document_id}

**Table Definition**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS basicindex.simple_index (
    term varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    doc_id INT NOT NULL,
    frequency INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (term,doc_id) 
)
```

Strangely, I have found that for the below two distinct words:

1. খুঁজে - present in doc 3, 16, 34
2. খুজে - present in doc 1

when I perform the below query:

**Query 1**:

```
select doc_id from basicindex.simple_index where term='খুঁজে';
```

**Query 2**:

```
select doc_id from basicindex.simple_index where term = 'খুজে';
```

both return 4 rows claiming that খুঁজে and খুজে are present in all the four documents.

From the logs I find that [Distinct Term, document id, frequency] খুঁজে  was inserted only for document id 1:

Inserting Indexes for খুজে ->{ DocID: 1, Frequency: 1}

('খুজে', 1, 1)

and খুঁজে was inserted in document ids 3, 16 and 34

Inserting Indexes for খুঁজে ->{ DocID: 3, Frequency: 1}

('খুঁজে', 3, 1)

Inserting Indexes for খুঁজে ->{ DocID: 16, Frequency: 2}

('খুঁজে', 16, 2)

Inserting Indexes for খুঁজে ->{ DocID: 34, Frequency: 1}

('খুঁজে', 34, 1)

Below are the unicode value for the terms:

খুঁজে [('খ', 2454), ('ু',2497), ('ঁ',2433), ('জ',2460), ('ে',2503)]

খুজে [('খ',2454), ('ু',2497), ('জ',2460), ('ে',2503)]

I am using **MYSQL version 8.0.13**. I request someone to please help me in understanding why MYSQL database is exhibiting such a behavior. Why is it not able to distinguish between 'খুঁজে' and 'খুজে'? What can I do to correct this?

I have attached the documents 1,3,16 and 34 and the input and output log files for your kind reference [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12nT4sTOa_sRjiv-BM7kNzupKcOXP2TwS?usp=sharing).

Comment: @Akina Hi thank you for your reply. The table collation detail is : basicindex.simple_index 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'. I tried [SET NAMES 'utf8';](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html) before executing the above two queries.
Can you please suggest me the fix for this? Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' is "accent-insensitive" and "case-insensitive". Select the collation correct for your case and specify it as shown in by answer. SET NAMES sets the charset only which matches a bunch of collations.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem seems to occur due to including accent insensitive (ai) in utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. I changed it to accent sensitive and it worked. `select doc_id from simple_index where term = 'খুঁজে'COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_ci;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> both return 4 rows claiming that খুঁজে and খুজে are present in all the four documents.

Check for used COLLATION. Specify needed COLLATE explicitly.

As an example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simple_index (
>     term varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
>     doc_id INT NOT NULL,
>     frequency INT NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (term,doc_id) 
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO simple_index VALUES
> ('খুঁজে', 1, 0 ),
> ('খুজে', 2, 0 );
> SELECT * FROM simple_index;
> ```
>
> | term | doc_id | frequency |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | খুঁজে | 1 | 0 |
> | খুজে | 2 | 0 |

> ```
> select doc_id from simple_index where term = 'খুঁজে';
> select doc_id from simple_index where term = 'খুজে';
> ```
>
> ```
> | doc_id |
> | -----: |
> |      1 |
> |      2 |
>
> | doc_id |
> | -----: |
> |      1 |
> |      2 |
> ```

> ```
> select doc_id from simple_index where term = 'খুঁজে'COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
> select doc_id from simple_index where term = 'খুজে' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
> ```
>
> ```
> | doc_id |
> | -----: |
> |      1 |
>
> | doc_id |
> | -----: |
> |      2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4611a080a845307eaeeb9b224ef399b5)*